# Gráficos dinamicos com google api

Tags: javascript

Pessoal estou fazendo um gráfico e preciso busca os dados via javascript do localStorage, porém não estou conseguindo entender a lógica, utilizando o php para busca a página fez sentido porém com o javascript não estou sabendo montar o array.

Estou fazendo da seguinte forma, porém nem entrar na aplicação entra:

```
   var itens = getData("graficoLinha_");

   function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     var variavel = "['Year', 'Membros', 'Visitantes'],";
     for(var i = 0; i < itens.length; i++){
     var objetos = itens[i][0];
     variavel = variavel + "['"+objetos.data+"', "+objetos.membros+", "+objetos.visitantes+"],"
    }
    variavel;
  ]);

    var options = {
     title: 'Membros x Visitantes',
     curveType: 'function',
     legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
```

o `getData` retorna para mim um array com tudo que estou passando por parâmetro, e nele eu tenho data, membro e visitante. No meu gráfico preciso pegar dinamicamente tudo isto, como fazer isto ?

Comment: Você usa o php e o getData para trazer as informações e salvar no localStorage respectivamente? Se for assim, como você está trazendo as informações um json, texto puro ...

Comment: @fernandoandrade não tudo esta no mobile